# CSS on Mouse Down

Tags: css

Usually I would use :hover, but I want my website to be accessible on touchscreen media too.

I know I can use :active, but as soon as I let go of the mouse button, it goes back to its inactive state.

Effectively I want:

> Mouse Down : Div goes green
>
> Mouse Up: Div stays green
>
> Mouse Down: Div goes red
>
> Mouse Up: Div stays red

Instead of:

> Mouse Down: Div goes green
>
> Mouse Up: Div goes red

Comment: the :active was what I was looking for since I dont need mobile support.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how to do a pure css toggle 'button' (CSS3 required):

```css
.toggle-button
{
  background-color: #FF0000;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.toggle-box:checked + .toggle-button
{
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-box" id="toggle-1" />
<label for="toggle-1" class="toggle-button">Click Me</label>
```

Of course, as always, IE fails at CSS (can't figure out the [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked)), so you're probably better off just using JavaScript.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can't nest <div> or <table> elements within a <label>, so JS or `:focus` (which isn't quite the same) is the only solution here.

Comment: [I'm not sure I follow](http://jsfiddle.net/2RPnR/)... I suppose I should mention that JS should be used to control the interactions, but it *is* possible to do some amount of toggle effects with HTML & CSS.

Comment: indeed, you can place the label elements inside a <div> or <td> element, but it's not quite the same thing.  For the former, only phrasing content is allowed, which means no other <div> elements. For the latter, you're increasing the markup quite a lot by having an extra <label> for each <td>. +1 for your answer, though, which is very helpful in most other cases.

Comment: This doesnt work on an anchor/link for me in FF. but does or buttons however.

Comment: @Grantunwin, not sure what you're referencing. Can you make a [reduced test case in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 151):

**Without relying on jQuery:**

The `:active` pseudo-class is used to apply css to elements while they're being clicked upon.

```
.button {
  color: red;
}
.button:active {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Remember if you have a hover state as well that it needs to be before the active. Otherwise the hover will override the click effect.
.button {
  color: red;
}
.button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.button:active {
  color: green;
}

Comment: This is not true. :active is applied on the active element. A element can be ":active" after a mouse click is performed.

Comment: +1 here is a JSBin http://jsbin.com/oquzab/1/edit As you've pointed out :active has to be the last item in the list for it to not get overridden by :hover :link and :visited.

Answer (score 9):

Use jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('#yo-content').click(function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('make-me-green');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#yo-content { 
    background-color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.make-me-green { 
    background-color: #33ff00 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="yo-content">Feel free to click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no pure-CSS way of achieving what you effectively want.

But jQuery could come handy there...

```
 // let's suppose your div's (on page load) initial state is red (#F00), 
 // and this flag will stand for it
 var initialState = true; // setup a global state flag
 $("#foo").mousedown( function() { // on mousedown
   $(this).css("background-color", intialState ? "#0F0" : "#F00"); // toggle bgColor
   initialState = !initialState; // toggle flag
 });
```

Instead of setting css properties, you could set/add/remove classnames if you'd like the presentational aspects to stay as CSS-centric as possible (which is a decent perspective).