# What is the mouse down selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have noticed that buttons and other elements have a default styling and behave in 3 steps: normal view, hover/focus view and mousedown/click view, in CSS I can change the styling of normal view and hover view like this:

```
button{
  background:#333;
  color:#FFF;
}

button:hover{
  background:#000;
  color:#EEE;
}
```

but how can I select the mousedown? I want something like this:

```
button:mousedown{
  //some styling
}
```

thanks

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725458/css-on-mouse-down

Comment: @x4vier: I don't think so. Then again, it's hard to tell what is meant by "mouse down" in this case.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

I think you mean the active state

```
button:active{
  //some styling
}
```

These are all the possible pseudo states a link can have in CSS:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link, same as regular 'a' */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* mouse over link */
a:focus {color:#0000FF;}   /* link has focus */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
```

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act

Comment: I don't want for links, I need for buttons, specially because in mobile devices hover makes an ugly glitch. Thanks

Comment: Add in that case I would style the button more fully. By adding a border:0; you lose the bezel around the button and the issue you are having.

Comment: @jansmolders86 Do you know if there is mouseover, mouseleave, mousedown, mouseup selector for a image or button in css?

Comment: @J.Fun not really, you could try to get the desired effect by using the :hover state for the over/leave and the :active for the down/up. But you can't differentiate between the two without javascript.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, this works for any element, not just buttons and links.

Answer (score 112):

I figured out that this behaves like a mousedown event:

```
button:active:hover {}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I I was looking for.  And that combination does behave like a mouse down selector on every device I have tried.  Thank you.  I believe this is the right answer.

Answer (score 38):

***Pro-tip Note:*** for some reason, CSS syntax needs the `:active` snippet **after** the `:hover` for the same element in order to be effective

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: CSS is evaluated in order so this makes sense; an element cannot become `:active` before it is `:hover`.

Comment: Also, `:active` has to be after `:focus` for it to work.  Thanks for pointing this out, I was really scratching my head as to why my CSS was having no effect!

Comment: @InTheZone Of course it can become :active before being :hover'ed. You can activate it with the keyboard, which doesn't hover.

Answer (score 5):

I recently found out that `:active:focus` does the same thing in css as `:active:hover` if you need to override a custom css library, they might use both.

Comment: For a button there is a visual different between the two if the user begins to click the button but then "cancels" the click by moving the mouse away before releasing the button. Only `:active:hover` visually reflects the button returning to its unclicked state.

Comment: They are not the same:
https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/

Answer (score 4):

Just for the reference while looking this for myself too. I have made a simple and nice looking buttons from 90s. On the click it looks like pressed just by changing the border colors in short.

**CSS:**

```css
#button {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

#button:active {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<button id="button">Click Here!</button>
```

**And here is the result:**

Not clicked
[image: not active button]

Clicked
[image: active button on click]