# How to change the size of an image on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I am trying to get an image to change from one size to a smaller size and then back to the other size with just one click. (you are clicking the image.) I have tried a good amount of options, but I haven't gotten it to change to a different size on click.

---

Here is the HTML part of the code (that is in question):

```
<p>Money: $<a id="clicks">0.00</a></p>
    <img src="Money.png" alt="Increase Money" title="Click Me to increase the Money." type="button" onclick="moneyOne()" class="clicked">
```

---

Here is the Javascript part of the code (that is in question):

```
var clicks = 0.00;
    function moneyOne() {
        clicks += 0.01;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

---

Here is the CSS part of the code (that is in question):

```
.clicked {
  width: 410px;
  height: 200px;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.clicked: {
  width: 400px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

---

Comment: 1) The code you submitted appears to be for changing the amount of currency a link tag (`a`) is displaying, not showing anything on changing the size of an image. 2) Your css has two `.clicked` style modifiers, and the second one has a typo

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried and tell us what it is supposed to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715274/what-is-the-mouse-down-selector-in-css

Comment: Add id to picture too and then modify through CSS and JavaScript. Just do search about transformation of pictures in Css and add these properties to picture also use some if statements.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Well, I know that the second `.clicked` has a typo since I don't know what to put after the `:` Well technically I haven't really tried anything, but I have looked up how to do it, I quickly got confused with it all. I did try some of the things I found, but none of them did what I wanted. But, I do know how to make it change sizes by just hovering over the image, but I want it to do exactly what the hover thing does when you move your mouse over the image and then off the image. I should state that I don't know much about coding, so I just want to keep things simple for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use trandsform, transition, and a timeout to remove the class.

```js
var clicks = 0.00;
var timer;
var img = document.querySelector(".clicked");

function moneyOne() {
  clicks += 0.01;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks.toFixed(2);
  img.classList.add("active");
  if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    img.classList.remove("active");
  }, 200);
};
```

```css
.clicked {
  width: 410px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.clicked.active {
  transform: scale(.6);
}
```

```html
<p>Money: $<a id="clicks">0.00</a></p>
<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg" alt="Increase Money" title="Click Me to increase the Money." type="button" onclick="moneyOne()" class="clicked">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clickActive = false;
var waitTime = 150;


document.querySelector("img").onclick = function() {
  if(!clickActive) {
    clickActive = true;
    this.style.animation = "getSmaller "+waitTime+"ms";
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.style.animation = "";
      clickActive = false;
    }, waitTime);
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes getSmaller {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50%{
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

/* for testing */
img {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
body {
  margin: 60px;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
```

Comment: The OP asked for the size to alternate of clicks. So when you click it once, it becomes large and shrinks when clicked again.

Comment: @AlexH "change from one size to a smaller size and then back to the other size" - Are you sure?

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Make sure to explain your answer. Code alone is hard to learn from.

Comment: The question? Yes, it is rather vague.

Comment: Admittedly, I'd take a more CSS-oriented approach, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the pseudo-class `:active` like that:

```
.clicked:active {
    width: 400px;
    height: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Well, I have tried this and it didn't work. It didn't even change the size of the image.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x8bu3n2a/4/
Have you tried to hold the mouse button down? This transition is too much I think to notice it...

Answer (score 0):

Adding the pseudo state `:active` works how you appear to want it.

```js
var clicks = 0.00;
    function moneyOne() {
        clicks += 0.01;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

```css
.clicked {
  width: 410px;
  height: 200px;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.clicked:active {
  width: 400px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<p>Money: $<a id="clicks">0.00</a></p>
    <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg" alt="Increase Money" title="Click Me to increase the Money." type="button" onclick="moneyOne()" class="clicked">
```