# On tap for CSS?

Tags: css, button

Recently I've been trying to make a clicker game so I added an effect where a button gets smaller when you click it and reverts when you release, but since many people simply tap a button, I've been wondering if there is a property sort of thing in CSS for tapping a button and not just clicking.

I didn't really find any solutions.
My code:

```css
.clicky:active { 
     transform: scale(0.95); 
     box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24); 
}
```

w */
}

Comment: You want the button to not shrink when users simply tap the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mouse down selector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715274/what-is-the-mouse-down-selector-in-css)

Comment: Clarification: Currently, when I click it, it shrinks, but when I tap it, nothing happens. Is there a way to make it always shrink?